# SVN Remote Repository reachable from one machine but not from another

Tags: svn, networking

I have setted an SVN server on a windows 2008 R2 server
I can browse/check-out the SVN Repositroy from my local machine, but my colleague can't from his machine (SVN "can't connect to server" message on TortoiseSVN & from Connection Timeout from Firefox )

However, both local machines are able to Telnet & http browse the remote server, and both firewalls are disactivated

*PS : This is not a programming question per-se so I apologize in advance. But I think all coders reading this may have experienced similar issues so the feedback found here can be sensible.*

Comment: What happens when you run the command line svn?  (e.g. "svn ls {protocol}:/{server}/{repo})?

Comment: SVN uses port 3690 by default unless it's running over SSH or SSL, see that you can telnet to that port. If there is no response on that port, you have a network or firewall problem. If there is response, there might be a client issue.

Comment: @Stabledog SVN works fine with some public repos on the problem machine. (I am sorry for my noobiness but I use Visual SVN Server & TortoiseSVN I dont know yet how to access SVN from command line I am getting a "command not recognized" message on the command prompt)

Comment: Do you both see the server on the same IP address? Do you have the same version of TortoiseSVN? Do you both use the same URL to connect to repository? (obvious question, but check it) Copy URL from working machine, email it, and paste it in non-working Tortoise.

Comment: Can you specify the error you're getting and the commands that every one is using. Are you using `http://` or `svn://`? What is the error message? There is a network issue going on. I also added the "networking" tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problematic workstation was behind a host building firewall and the port were blocked at that level. *Sigh...*